# Asp.net Localization - Should I use a button?

Tags: asp.net, localization

This is a pretty basic question.

Since browsers have a culture setting that the web app uses to decide which locale to use,  should I still have a "language" button for users to be able to override the culture?

Why or Why Not?

To me it doesn't make sense to have a button there if the user had already set their language in their system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should.

One of the reasons outlined on the [ASP.NET Localisation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx) is that a user may have a preference for reading certain types of websites in a specific language (i.e. technical websites in English). This is a good reason.

There are other reasons as well (i.e. the translation may not be great, a different user than typical is using the given computer, etc, etc).

Comment: Great thanks... looks like the only answer "must" be the right answer.